# Dockerizing MERN with nginx connect 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, docker, nginx

I made an app using nodejs, react, mongodb, nginx and tried dockering.

It's a very simple app.

When you write something, you just show it.

[image]

However, the input from the frontend is not delivered to the backend.

When I type something, 404 error is shown.

[image]

my github: https://github.com/k3kys/prac

**frontend**

nginx/default.conf

```
server {
  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

list.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/users");
      setName(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

signup.js

```
  const submitHandler = async (e) => {

    await axios.post("/api/users", {
      name: name,
    });
```

***backend***

server.js

```
app.use(cors());
app.use("/api/users", userRouter)
```

***nginx***

default.conf

```
upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:5000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
    
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db/
    networks:
      - net

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - api
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
    networks:
      - net

  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./backend
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./backend:/app
    networks:
      - net

  frontend:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

I did my best to make a brief.

I would appreciate it if you could refer to the git hub for details.

Thanks for your help.

error message in docker logs
[image]

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Can you cURL your API without problems?

Comment: yes,  run app locally without docker-compose, very very fine

Comment: R.karlus very very thankyou !! u are right!  I change app.use("/api/users", userRouter) => ("/users, userRouter) thank you sir T_T

Comment: NP, good to hear you could solve it, post the answer ;D